# Check if focus is on div with contenteditable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if a div is focused the same way that I can check if an input is focused in Firefox? See snippet.

```js
$('.element').on('focus', function(e) {
  if( $('.element').is(':focus') ) console.log('Focused!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="element">Click here</div>
<input type="text" class="element" value="Click here" />
```

Comment: but it work correct! what is your problem? do you want to when an element showed this alert throw?

Comment: Working for both, what is the problem?

Comment: I just added that it doesn't work in Firefox! Sorry about that.

Comment: @HassanSadeghi In Firefox (62) on Mac only the input returns "Focused!"

Comment: You want v.62 or higher? answers below work on v.59. Add it to the question.

Comment: `$(document.activeElement).is('.element')` solved my problem! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it. Anyone has a better solution?

```js
$('.element').on('focus', function(e) {
  if( $(document.activeElement).is('.element') ) console.log('Focused!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="element">Click here</div>
<input type="text" class="element" value="Click here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in firefox

```js
$('.element').on('focus', function(e) {
   console.log('Focused!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" class="element">Click here</div>
<input type="text" class="element" value="Click here" />
```

Comment: Yes, however what I didn't mention is that I want to run a JS timer that checks if the div has focus and that does not work with `$('.element').is(':focus')` in Firefox. `$(document.activeElement).is('.element')` seems to work tho!

Comment: @SeaBass in that case, don't use a timer, and just listen to `focusin` and `focusout` to keep track of state

Comment: @SeaBass Perhaps you can include the higher level objective in your question, so we can help you. Right now the only objective is only to _check if an input is focused in Firefox_

Comment: @emineminems I'm doing a "poor-mans" push where I reload some content every x seconds, but only if an editable field is not in focus.